# Сортировка по дате

Tags: c, c++

Когда имеется ввиду "сортировка по дате", это означает, что нужно сортировать по годам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я бы имел ввиду сортировать по полному времени, вплоть до миллисекунд, подразумевая под этим приведение даты к секундам/миллисекундам.

Comment: тоесть так: сортировать те месяцы, года которых равны -> сортировать те дни, месяцы которых равны....... и тд . может так ?

Comment: Да, "поуровневое" сравнение - это оно

Comment: Ещё, если можно, подскажите алгоритм такой сортировки (на словах) с использованием рекурсии.

Comment: Можете использовать quick_sort - он рекурсивен, в качестве компаратора можете воспользоватся функцией приведенной в ответе @dzhioev

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

По годам, затем по месяцам, затем по числу. Функция сравнения выглядит так:

```
bool cmp_dates(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (d1.year < d2.year) ||
           (d1.year == d2.year && d1.month < d2.month) ||
           (d1.year == d2.year && d1.month == d2.month && d1.day < d2.day);
}
```